How to optimize vmware 13 for gaming on apple silicon?
Is there a way? I set the graphic memory to 8gb and 6 core processors with 10 gb rams and it still run at less than 30fps on windows 11 arm 64 with 3d acceleration on. If not any recommendation for other vm?

Did you tag this fallout 4 because that's the game you're trying to play?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
